# Arrows not compatible when testing in FireFox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, webkit, css-animations

I have an issue that is browser compatibility related: I'm building a portfolio website and use arrows down and up on every page. These arrows work as a link (a href) and take you to the next page when you click on it. While building this, I tested it in my localhost, which I use Chrome for. The arrows behave how I wanted (they jump up and down) and have the position on the page I wanted, which is 60 px from the bottom. However, when I test my project in another browser, like Firefox,  these arrows take the wrong position on the page (way much further down). Does one of you can tell me what's going wrong here? I have no idea how to fix this. Important to know is that I designed my arrow myself with css-borders and rotation. Look at the code below (HTML, and CSS).

[CSS code and design of the arrow]

My Images

- [CSS code to make the arrow jump and down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrNv6.png)
- [CSS code and design for the arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0Z6o.png)
- [HTML code for the scroll button/arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIrln.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you share your code (from the images) as code block? Just use three back ticks arround the code. Text is much easier then a image.

Answer (score 0):

when using `position: absolute` you must make parent **relative**.
In your case you added `position:absolute;` to `.scroll-btn` so you must add `position: relative` to it's parent. here is `<a href="#about">`.

**NOTE:** if still difference in multiple browser, add `display:block,/*inline-block*/` to tag `<a>` because default `<a>` display is `inline` and if you add display to tag, browser understood, and if you don't add display to your `absolute` tags, each browser make it by default values of it and show wrong.